# Do I need a blocking diode for bulk capacitors connected to solar panels?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, solar-energy

I have two 100 uF bulk capacitors connected directly to a solar panel which connects to a BQ24298 charge controller on a Particle ESeries microcontroller.

I have them left unpopulated because I don't know whether the reverse current could damage the solar panel (5.5 watt 6 volt).

Would it be bad to connect these capacitors without a blocking diode? How about the smaller bypass capacitors?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your solar panels are not in the schematic, but are you afraid that the panels will charge the batteries to a relatively high voltage, panels become shaded and now the capacitor voltage is higher than what the panels would be able to produce?

Comment: @winny Yes sorry my panels connect directly to the power jack J1. Yes Im worried that if the solar panels get shaded, then the charged capacitors will discharge into the solar panel and damage it.

Comment: Is it a bare solar cell or does it come with built in blocking diode?

Comment: No built in blocking diode

Comment: Calling @SolarMike

Comment: "In our tests, in order to drive reverse current through the panel, you need to have a source voltage that is higher than  Voc of the panel. So if your capacitors were ~6.5V or higher there could be some reverse current. If they are lower, we don't see a risk.

We have run 2A in reverse current through panels for a few hours. The panel warmed up but there was no damage that we could measure." -This is what the solar panel company told me. My capacitor voltage would just match the voltage of my solar panels right? So with the 6V panel, they shouldnt rise higher than 6V so I should be good?